# webservices on android eclipse

Tags: android, web-services

i am new to android/eclipse(java),in fact this forum too.

Has any one met this situation?

Get input from the user and display the appropriate result by consuming web service from android/eclipse.is there any examples available?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Use the search function. There are TOO many examples

Comment: which webservice u will be using like wcf webservices etc and also specify in your question u want to use ksoap or json

Comment: I am following SOAP method mam

Answer (score 1):

I am posting Link of tutorial

Here basic android tutorial to access web service in android [basic ksoap android tutorial](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.in/2010/11/basic-ksoap-android-tutorial.html)

and for creating webservice in java use this Tutorial [How to create java based web service](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BottomUpAxis2WebService/bu_tutorial.html)

Write a web service using java and Then by using ksoap library you will get response. Then Format that response according to your requirement. code for reference:

```
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/"; 
private static final String URL ="http://localhost/Web_Service.asmx?";// replace it by your Webservice URL
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "Function_Name";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "Soap Action";

SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 
request.addProperty("parm_name",prm_value);// Parameter for Method
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
try 
{
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);//call the eb service Method
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}//Next task is to get Response and format that response
    SoapObject response;
    response= (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
```

Answer (score 0):

there are too may example for same Please Google ..................

this is only for initiation

Soap

http://android.vexedlogic.com/2011/04/17/android-lists-iv-accessing-and-consuming-a-soap-web-service-i/

http://seesharpgears.blogspot.in/2010/11/basic-ksoap-android-tutorial.html

Other

http://webhole.net/2011/11/15/android-tutorial-how-to-post-data-from-an-android-app-to-a-website/

http://apachejava.blogspot.in/2011/06/partial-http-post-show-data-webview.html

http://senior.ceng.metu.edu.tr/2009/praeda/2009/01/11/a-simple-restful-client-at-android/